# overflow scroll is not coming for disabled attributes in IE 11

Tags: html, scroll, scrollbar, internet-explorer-11

I am not able to get scrollbar in a disabled select attribute in IE, whereas in chrome it comes. I have tried using -ms-overflow-style:scrollbar, it works but for disabled select the scroll is also disabled. please help

[please find the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVK8Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow: hidden;` like this:

```
.yourclass { 
overflow:hidden
    }
```

The overflow hidden tag hides any vertical or orizontal scrollbars, but you can also specificly target an axis like this:

```
.yourclass{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Or the Y-axis:

```
.yourclass{
    overflow-y:hidden;
    }
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: thanks @mkyriacou1994,
Overflow hidden just hides the values ( which is happening here by default)  but i need a scrollbar to see all the values and what values have been selected in the dropdown, thanks in advance!

Comment: I try to make a test with disabled select and find that it remains disabled and not show the option to scroll the drop down in both IE and chrome. It is better if you post a sample code. So that we can try to check what exact thing you are doing in your code.